# How to programmatically/iteratively make several Views invisible?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Layout that occupies the bottom half of the display.
My intention is to re-use this Layout for 4 different functions.
 In the upper portion of the display, I have another Layout hosting 4 buttons to select these functions. [My Android Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HO0N.png)
What I'm trying to do is, upon selecting 1 of the 4 buttons, wipe the entire bottom Layout (make all Views, Widgets, etc have GONE visibility). After clearing the Layout, it will make visible only the Views relevant to the selected function.
In learning how to programmatically change attributes of a View, I have not found an alternative to using `findViewById` individually for each item. This quickly becomes cluttered as it requires 2 lines of code per element.
[Kotlin code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH2ha.png)
**Is there a way to build a template to achieve this goal without knowing/listing each View? Such as iterating through all child Views of a Layout?**

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numChildren(parentLayout); i++) {
parentLayout.Child(i).visibility = GONE
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to iterate the children. Just change the visibility of the parent. Also, look up Android view binding.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can do it exactly as you mentioned - iterating through the child views:

```
parentLayout.children.forEach {
    view ->  view.isVisible = false
}
```